# Why does using .map() to try and build an html table not working?

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6

I would like to generate a table by passing JSON into .map() and then append it as a child to the main table.  As you will see below, when you run the code, it appends my concatenated  and  as a string to the table.  It does not create the actual rows and cells.  Thanks for any help you can provide.

```
var data = {
  'results': [
    {
      'firstName': 'John',
      'lastName': 'Doe',
      'email': 'jdoe@mail.com'
    },
    {
      'firstName': 'Luke',
      'lastName': 'Doe',
      'email': 'loe@mail.com'
    },
    {
      'firstName': 'Sarah',
      'lastName': 'Doe',
      'email': 'sdoe@mail.com'
    },
    {
      'firstName': 'July',
      'lastName': 'Doe',
      'email': 'julydoe@mail.com'
    },
    {
      'firstName': 'Jane',
      'lastName': 'Doe',
      'email': 'janedoe@mail.com'
    }    
  ]
}

var generateHtml = data.results.map(function(item) {
  return '<tr><td>' + item.firstName + '</td></tr>';
})

document.getElementById('example').append(generateHtml);

<table id="example" border="2"></table>
```

Comment: I think you want `.reduce()` as that will return a SINGLE string. `.map()` will return another array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should return actual element objects:

```
let generateElements = data.results.map(function (item) {
    let row = document.createElement("tr");

    row.appendChild(document.createElement("td")).textContent =
        item.firstName;

    return row;
});
```

then call `append` with each element as an argument:

```
document.getElementById("example").tBodies[0].append(...generateElements);
```

This has the advantage of protecting you from XSS and such in `item.firstName`.

If you’d like to support browsers that don’t support the spread syntax `...generateElements`, it’s probably easiest not to use `append` (polyfilled or not) at all:

```
var target = document.getElementById("example").tBodies[0];

data.results.forEach(function (item) {
    var row = document.createElement("tr");

    row.appendChild(document.createElement("td")).textContent =
        item.firstName;

    target.appendChild(row);
});
```

```js
let data = {
  'results': [
    {
      'firstName': 'John',
      'lastName': 'Doe',
      'email': 'jdoe@mail.com'
    },
    {
      'firstName': 'Luke',
      'lastName': 'Doe',
      'email': 'loe@mail.com'
    },
    {
      'firstName': 'Sarah',
      'lastName': 'Doe',
      'email': 'sdoe@mail.com'
    },
    {
      'firstName': 'July',
      'lastName': 'Doe',
      'email': 'julydoe@mail.com'
    },
    {
      'firstName': 'Jane',
      'lastName': 'Doe',
      'email': 'janedoe@mail.com'
    }    
  ]
};

let generateElements = data.results.map(function (item) {
  let row = document.createElement("tr");

  row.appendChild(document.createElement("td")).textContent =
    item.firstName;

  return row;
});

document.getElementById('example').tBodies[0].append(...generateElements);
```

```html
<table id="example" border="2">
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @DavidWaters and for limiting browser support to only those using Experimental technologies. ;)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan: `append()`? The original question used it.

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget to join the array. If you're returning an array of string you need to use `innerHTML`, else create the dom objects and append them manually.

```js
var data = {
 "results": [
   {
     "firstName": "John",
      "lastName": "Doe",
      "email": "jdoe@mail.com"
    },
   {
     "firstName": "Luke",
      "lastName": "Doe",
      "email": "loe@mail.com"
    },
   {
     "firstName": "Sarah",
      "lastName": "Doe",
      "email": "sdoe@mail.com"
    },
   {
     "firstName": "July",
      "lastName": "Doe",
      "email": "julydoe@mail.com"
    },
   {
     "firstName": "Jane",
      "lastName": "Doe",
      "email": "janedoe@mail.com"
    }    
  ]
}

var generateHtml = data.results.map(function(item){
  return "<tr><td>"+item.firstName+"</td></tr>";
})


document.getElementById('example').innerHTML = generateHtml.join('');
```

```html
<table id="example" border=2>

</table>
```

Comment: Where have you seen `.html()` and `$`?

Answer (score 1):

When you use `append`, you need to pass an DOM element, not just a string.
Use `.html(generateHtml)` or `.innerHTML = generateHtml.join('')` or create nodes than use `append` function.

Example

```js
var data = {
    "results": [
    {
      "firstName": "John",
      "lastName": "Doe",
      "email": "jdoe@mail.com"
    },
   {
      "firstName": "Luke",
      "lastName": "Doe",
      "email": "loe@mail.com"
    },
   {
      "firstName": "Sarah",
      "lastName": "Doe",
      "email": "sdoe@mail.com"
    },
   {
      "firstName": "July",
      "lastName": "Doe",
      "email": "julydoe@mail.com"
    },
   {
      "firstName": "Jane",
      "lastName": "Doe",
      "email": "janedoe@mail.com"
    }    
  ]
}

var generateHtml = data.results.map(function(item){
    return "<tr><td>"+item.firstName+"</td></tr>";
});

document.getElementById("example").innerHTML = generateHtml.join('');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="example" border=2>

</table>
```